# How can infer return type of a function using the parameters supplied?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have a generic function whose return type is based on the input type. How can ensure type safety for the return type correctly based on the parameter supplied?

**Example**

```
interface IKeyboardService{
    type() : void;
}

class KeyboardService{
    type(){
        
    }
}

interface IMouseService{
    move() : void;
}

class MouseService{
    move(){

    }
}

interface ServiceTypeMapping{
    Keyboard: IKeyboardService,
    Mouse: IMouseService
}

type ServiceType = keyof ServiceTypeMapping;

function getService<T extends ServiceTypeMapping, K extends keyof ServiceTypeMapping>(serviceType : K): typeof T[K]{
    switch(serviceType){
        case 'Keyboard':
            return new KeyboardService();
        case 'Mouse':
            return new MouseService();
    }
    throw new Error("No implementation error");
}

//This should be an error
const mouseService = getService('Keyboard');
```

I am passing keyboard and expecting IKeyboardService. At the moment, this is erroring at return type of getService.

you can play here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-leut1x

Thank you.

Comment: You can remove `T` and just use `function getService<K extends keyof ServiceTypeMapping>(serviceType: K): ServiceTypeMapping[K] {` but typing the implementation is tricky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function getService(serviceType: 'Keyboard'): KeyboardService;
function getService(serviceType: 'Mouse'): MouseService;
function getService(serviceType: keyof ServiceTypeMapping): ServiceTypeMapping[keyof ServiceTypeMapping] {
    switch(serviceType){
        case 'Keyboard':
            return new KeyboardService();
        case 'Mouse':
            return new MouseService();
        default:
            throw new Error("No implementation error");
    }
}
```

[**Typescript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDSCmBPARgezAJwCYGV4YDcBLYeAbwChproAXRAB3gAoBKSmz6KmgXwv4VQkGAFlUAVwjw8hEuR7UAtqgIt2FRdH6CiAO1r4AZmFLRZxUgBVG8UWAYN9Acw40EKdNgBccJGkxcfEt4ABotcSl4X0jpC3kBTXomc2D5GxSAXmgAayRUI1S5a1t7RxcAbk0jCT1gWiJUPWhneFp40mZpYvgM6OgAcg8A7AHWX2GvIJ6qmrqGppa2jpZukL7fAdj4MZjJOLTSWdr6xubW9sPVq43c-MKVvrKnPWdxovXShxfnAG08xAFD7pL7lV4AXWgbmoEAA7kRaMAABZdG62DRcGjASDwQaTQIDbxaTHUDBtCQYZp6eCwvyeQIrNhVEnQbHSQbbQnEklk2gUqk06DbRmsZkkrDwEwSEC0Ikszi0JEYVC06m0gCiGGVGGYACIAHKoaBEJQMEDwJTwAxgBbNfDa3WirQ6TQAeldViRRBgECRkhAWGgyFxYDtWtQGCETQgtGgKiiKz2Cau0GyF0ZQ38UzGVSAA)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using a conditional type on the return:

```
function getService<T extends ServiceType>(serviceType: T) {
    let returnService
    switch(serviceType){
        case 'Keyboard':
            returnService = new KeyboardService();
            break;
        case 'Mouse':
            returnService = new MouseService();
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error("No implementation error");
    }
    return returnService as T extends 'Keyboard' ? KeyboardService : MouseService
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDSCmBPARgezAJwCYGV4YDcBLYeAbwChproAXRAB3gAoBKSmz6KmgXwv4VQkGAFlUAVwjw8hEuR7UAtqgIt2FRdH6CiAO1r4AZmFLRZxUgBVG8UWAYN9Acw40EKdNgBccJGkxcfEt4ABotcSl4X0jpC3kBTXomc2D5GxSAXmgAayRUI1S5a1t7RxcAbk0jCT1gWiJUPWhneFp40gAeK2h4AA9DPSwYDvgM%20AA%20ZmlisdtfK1ZoN2oQNugMNokMPVGtCAB3IlpgAAtptJKmDS4aYEh4aAByDwDsJ%208tW%20pN2m3dy6PbJ6eAHPyeQKjNhVb5cZCbMA5GHfe7SZ6xeAfL7fX7-UbQYGg6AYqGsZGw6jw%20CI8lcLDwEwSEC0T4Umi0U4YVBgkFggCiGC5GGYACIAHKoaBEJQMNZKeAGMANJq9QWoDAislaficXE7DZbHb4yDQHr9QbDZ6vLxYJ7QAD84LeQVm0BikjigMSFAA9D6rKciDAIKdJCAsNBkI8wM18EKhE0ILRoCooqN3WnAQSWm0oS9-DanlqgA)